# Passenger 5.0 with legacy Rails 2.3 app won't boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Recently updated Passenger from 4.x to 5.0.7 on my Ubuntu server. Sadly, this broke one of my older application still running Rails 2.3.15, even though Passenger claims to support >= Rails 2.3.x in its new 5.x versions.

According to the new Passenger 5.0 documentation I had to create a config.ru file after which I am presented with the following error:

```
exit (SystemExit)
  /var/www/myrailsapp/config/boot.rb:70:in `exit'
  /var/www/myrailsapp/config/boot.rb:70:in `rescue in load_rails_gem'
  /var/www/myrailsapp/config/boot.rb:63:in `load_rails_gem'
  /var/www/myrailsapp/config/boot.rb:58:in `load_initializer'
  /var/www/myrailsapp/config/boot.rb:43:in `run'
  /var/www/myrailsapp/config/boot.rb:16:in `boot!'
  /var/www/myrailsapp/config/boot.rb:114:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /var/www/myrailsapp/config/environment.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:107:in `eval'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:107:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

The crash (or exit) is caused by a rescue in the boot.rb which reads:

```
def load_rails_gem
  if version = self.class.gem_version
    gem 'rails', version
  else
    gem 'rails'
  end
rescue Gem::LoadError => load_error
  $stderr.puts %(Missing the Rails #{version} gem. Please `gem install -v=#{version} rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or co$
  exit 1
end
```

Obviously, the Rails 2.3.15 gem is (still) installed and unchanged in between the Passenger update process. For some reason it won't load Rails and I can't seem to figure out why. 'gem list' displays all gems correctly (including rails 2.3.15) and it seems Passenger is using the correct instances through RVM.

The rest of the environment variables seem to be in order as well

```
APACHE_PID_FILE = /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
rvm_bin_path = /usr/local/rvm/bin
GEM_HOME = /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551
APACHE_RUN_USER = www-data
SHELL = /bin/bash
IRBRC = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/.irbrc
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXDL9Zb9
MY_RUBY_HOME = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551
USER = chris
_system_type = Linux
rvm_path = /usr/local/rvm
IN_PASSENGER = 1
RACK_ENV = production
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD = true
rvm_prefix = /usr/local
PATH = /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin
APACHE_LOG_DIR = /var/log/apache2
WSGI_ENV = production
PWD = /var/www/myrailsapp
LANG = C
APACHE_RUN_GROUP = www-data
NODE_PATH = /usr/share/passenger/node
_system_arch = i386
NODE_ENV = production
_system_version = 14.04
rvm_version = 1.26.10 (latest)
HOME = /home/chris
SHLVL = 0
RAILS_ENV = production
SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) SVN/1.8.8 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.7
LOGNAME = chris
GEM_PATH = /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global
PASSENGER_APP_ENV = production
APACHE_RUN_DIR = /var/run/apache2
APACHE_LOCK_DIR = /var/lock/apache2
RUBY_VERSION = ruby-1.9.3-p551
_system_name = Ubuntu
```

#### UPDATE

After commenting out the rescue block in the config/boot.rb, Passenger now throws a new error which prevents Rails 2.3.15 to load correctly:

```
Unable to activate actionpack-2.3.15, because rack-1.4.5 conflicts with rack (~> 1.1.3) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Any idea on how to fix this? If possible I would prefer to monky patch this in my local installation over creating completely seperate gemsets in RVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to resolve this dependency conflict was to create a seperate GemSet in RVM for my legacy Rails 2.3 sites.

While quite a bit of work to gather all the required gems I needed to reinstall from the projects in a pre-Gemfile era, I am convinced this is the best solution for the future.